# How do I compile pipes in Windows?

Tags: c, pipe, computer-science

I am using MinGW as my compiler and I do not know how to get pipes to work on it. I have tried the function pipe() and fork() but neither of them seem to be working. Does anybody know how to create pipes on Windows, specifically on this compiler. What files do I need to include?? Thanks!

Comment: `fork()` and `pipe()` are specific to *nix systems, you need to use Windows libraries for multi-process and multi-threaded applications.

Comment: What specific libraries and functions do I have to use?